# ServiceStack Bundler - Linked files

Tags: servicestack, bundling-and-minification

[ServiceStack Bundler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Bundler) doesn't recognize linked files.

Using Visual Studio 2012, i've a solution folder containing the core of JS and Less, and SS Bundler is working like a charm!

Now i'm trying to separate the unit tests in a different project, testing those linked files but when i build the Website, SS Bundler don't find the files (it finds if i add them directly, without the linking feature), outputs an error like the files doesn't exists.

Does anyone has any idea how to achieve this?